# ava.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer in NumberPickerPreference

Tags: android

```
public class NumberPickerPreference extends DialogPreference {

public static final int DEFAULT_MAX_VALUE = 100;
public static final int DEFAULT_MIN_VALUE = 0;
public static final boolean DEFAULT_WRAP_SELECTOR_WHEEL = true;

private final int minValue;
private final int maxValue;
private final boolean wrapSelectorWheel;

private NumberPicker picker;
private int value;

public NumberPickerPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.dialogPreferenceStyle);
}

public NumberPickerPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.NumberPickerPreference);
    minValue =  a.getInteger(R.styleable.NumberPickerPreference_minValue, DEFAULT_MIN_VALUE);
    maxValue = a.getInteger(R.styleable.NumberPickerPreference_maxValue, DEFAULT_MAX_VALUE);
    wrapSelectorWheel = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.NumberPickerPreference_wrapSelectorWheel, DEFAULT_WRAP_SELECTOR_WHEEL);
    a.recycle();
}

@Override
protected View onCreateDialogView() {
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

    picker = new NumberPicker(getContext());
    picker.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    FrameLayout dialogView = new FrameLayout(getContext());
    dialogView.addView(picker);

    return dialogView;
}

@Override
protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {
    super.onBindDialogView(view);
    picker.setMinValue(minValue);
    picker.setMaxValue(maxValue);
    picker.setWrapSelectorWheel(wrapSelectorWheel);
    picker.setValue(getValue());
}

@Override
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
    if (positiveResult) {
        picker.clearFocus();
        int newValue = picker.getValue();
        if (callChangeListener(newValue)) {
            setValue(newValue);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
    return a.getInt(index, minValue);
}

@Override
protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restorePersistedValue, Object defaultValue) {

    setValue(restorePersistedValue ? getPersistedInt(minValue) : (Integer) defaultValue);
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
    persistInt(this.value);
}

public int getValue() {
    return this.value;
}
}
```

this is my preferences.xml

```
 <PreferenceCategory>
            <com.techjini.highlightvideo.util.NumberPickerPreference
                android:defaultValue="2"
                android:entries="@array/highlighttime"
                android:entryValues="@array/highlighttime"
                android:key="prefPastsec"
                android:summary="@string/pref_past_hightlight"
                android:title="@string/pref_past_hightlight"
                preference:maxValue="18"
                preference:minValue="35"
                preference:wrapSelectorWheel="false"

                />


            <com.techjini.highlightvideo.util.NumberPickerPreference
                android:defaultValue="2"
                android:entries="@array/highlighttime"
                android:entryValues="@array/highlighttime"
                android:key="prefFuturesec"
                android:summary="@string/pref_future_highlight"
                android:title="@string/pref_future_highlight"
                preference:maxValue="18"
                preference:minValue="35"
                preference:wrapSelectorWheel="false"
                />


        </PreferenceCategory>
```

and i m calling in below fragment:

```
public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        for (int i = 0; i < getPreferenceScreen().getPreferenceCount(); ++i) {
            Preference preference = getPreferenceScreen().getPreference(i);
            if (preference instanceof PreferenceGroup) {
                PreferenceGroup preferenceGroup = (PreferenceGroup) preference;
                for (int j = 0; j < preferenceGroup.getPreferenceCount(); ++j) {
                    Preference singlePref = preferenceGroup.getPreference(j);
                    updatePreference(singlePref);
                }
            } else {
                updatePreference(preference);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        updatePreference(findPreference(key));
    }

    private void updatePreference(Preference preference) {
        if (preference == null)
            return;


        if (preference instanceof NumberPickerPreference) {
            NumberPickerPreference listPreference = (NumberPickerPreference) preference;
            preference.setSummary(listPreference.getValue());
            return;

        }
        if (preference instanceof EditTextPreference) {

            EditTextPreference editTextPref = (EditTextPreference) preference;
            preference.setSummary(editTextPref.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

For `ListPreference` it is working fine. Same thing I have changed with `NumberPickerPreference`. But its not working Properly as I am getting

> class cast Exception in NumberPickerPreference.java:88 at line  setValue(restorePersistedValue ? getPersistedInt(minValue) : (Integer) defaultValue);

Please suggest me what am doing wrong why its giving class cast Exception .

Comment: Could you add Log info?

Comment: https://paste.ofcode.org/Bkim7HfjSV2btVRvKAnEJw  this is Log @KeLiuyue

Comment: You can check `setValue(restorePersistedValue ? getPersistedInt(minValue) : (Integer) defaultValue);` code .  `defaultValue` was Object . You should make sure `defaultValue` is `int` .And `(Integer) defaultValue)` was not valid .

Comment: setValue(restorePersistedValue ? getPersistedInt(minValue) : (Integer) 2);  i have changed this then also same issue

Comment: Use `Integer.parseInt((String) defaultValue);` to have a try.

Comment: https://paste.ofcode.org/TyFN9M27mn2g9C5pH6AiQe now this exception coming when i try to get Value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153214/discussion-between-adevelopment-and-keliuyue).

Comment: change `preference.setSummary(listPreference.getValue());`  to `preference.setSummary(listPreference.getValue() +"");`

Comment: Could you solve your problem？

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1. **java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer**

   **change**

   ```
   setValue(restorePersistedValue ? getPersistedInt(minValue) : (Integer) defaultValue);
   ```

   **to**

   ```
   int mDefaultValue = Integer.parseInt((String) defaultValue)
   setValue(restorePersistedValue ? getPersistedInt(minValue) : mDefaultValue);
   ```
2. **Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID**

   **change**

   ```
   preference.setSummary(listPreference.getValue());
   ```

   **to**

   ```
   preference.setSummary(listPreference.getValue() +"");
   ```

**Note**

If value is Object , you want to convert `Object value` to `int value`.

You can `Integer.parseInt((String) value);` .

If you code like this `tv.setText(value)`, the `value` must be `String`.

You can use `tv.setText(value + "");`、`tv.setText(String.valueOf(value));`

**Edit**

In your `setValue(restorePersistedValue ? getPersistedInt(minValue) : (Integer) defaultValue);`.

1. make sure `restorePersistedValue` return `boolean Data`
2. make sure `getPersistedInt(minValue)` return `int Data`
3. make sure `defaultValue` is not null and covert to `int Data`

Comment: This is not working i have set value int mDefaultValue = Integer.parseInt((String) defaultValue)
setValue(restorePersistedValue ? getPersistedInt(minValue) : mDefaultValue); still same exception

Comment: You can check it.

Answer (score 0):

> setValue(restorePersistedValue ? getPersistedInt(minValue) : (Integer) defaultValue);

will throw **ClassCastException**: String cannot be cast to Integer, So make sure you are using the same return type in both argument like:

```
setValue(restorePersistedValue ? getPersistedInt(minValue) : Integer.parseInt(defaultValue));
```

And

> preference.setSummary(listPreference.getValue());

will throw **Resources$NotFoundException**: String resource ID, because It take integer agrument as resource type. So it's better to wrap the value in String, like:

```
preference.setSummary(String.valueOf(listPreference.getValue()));
```

Comment: @Akhlisesh Dubey  all value is not coming in number picker

Comment: @adevelopment Have you checked you TypedArray? Might be you have some empty or text value in your @array/highlighttime.

Comment: OK wait let me check

Comment: I kind of hope Akhilesh did not die waiting. Pushes me assuming, his guess was correct.